# Bezier Curve -Undo only Last Node

Tags: inkscape, vector, bezier-curve

For a map outline which has large number of nodes concentrated in a small area , `is it possible to undo only the last drawn node` in case of an error?

Currently undo clears the entire path.

Ofcourse these nodes can be adjusted later , but  if this option is available then it would be more faster.

Comment: Undo will only work on the last node if you have not committed or closed the path. Otherwise, you'll have to delete the nodes or edit them manually.

Comment: The path is uncommited and unclosed .... and on hitting  Escape , the entire path gets deleted instead of only the last node.

Comment: Don't hit Escape. I've added an answer now.

Comment: For next time: Help > Keys and Mouse Reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have not committed the path, and the path is also not closed, and you still have the Bézier tool selected, then Undo should work.  The shortcut is for undo is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  You can also delete the nodes back sequentially using either <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Example

[image]

If you have committed or closed the path, then you will have to edit it manually using the Edit Path by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>